# Cannot repair boot with Boot-Repair into Ubuntu 22.10

Tags: boot, 22.04, grub-efi, 22.10

I have accidentally deleted some files on my Ubuntu 22.10 (bin, lip, sbin). Then I restarted my PC and it is not booting anymore. I have inserted an old bootable Ubuntu 22.04 and install boot-repair, when I run it I get this error:

```
Please enable a repository containing the [grub-efi] packages in the  
software sources of Ubuntu 22.10 (mapper/vgubuntu-root). Then try again.
```

See the Pastebin: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Bp6FV5Kc5m/plain/

```
============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/nvme0n1.
 => Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    for (hd0,msdos1)/boot/grub. It also embeds following components:
    
    modules
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    biosdisk fshelp fat exfat ext2 ntfs ntfscomp part_msdos
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

nvme0n1p1: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/BOOT/fbx64.efi /efi/BOOT/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/fwupdx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg

nvme0n1p2: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       LVM2_member
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  MSWIN4.1: FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /efi/boot/bootx64.efi 
                       /efi/boot/grubx64.efi /efi/boot/mmx64.efi


================================ 1 OS detected =================================

OS#1:   Ubuntu 22.10 on mapper/vgubuntu-root

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: WhiskeyLake-U GT2 [UHD Graphics 620] EFI VGA from Intel Corporation
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, jammy, x86_64)

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: 1.23.0(1.23) from Dell Inc.
The firmware is EFI-compatible, and is set in EFI-mode for this live-session.
SecureBoot disabled (confirmed by mokutil).
BootCurrent: 0002
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0001,0002
Boot0000* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,5ad9202a-0041-401f-a660-ad899188dd67,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0001* UEFI: PC601 NVMe SK hynix 512GB, Partition 1  HD(1,GPT,5ad9202a-0041-401f-a660-ad899188dd67,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\Boot\BootX64.efi)..BO
Boot0002* UEFI: Generic Flash Disk 8.07, Partition 1    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(1,0)/HD(1,MBR,0x271743,0x800,0x1d4b800)..BO


============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

sda : notGPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has-noESP,  usb-disk,   not-mmc, has-os,    no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes
nvme0n1 : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, no-os, no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

mapper/vgubuntu-root    : is-os,    64, apt-get,    signed grub-pc grub-efi ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ok, update-grub,    not-far
nvme0n1p1   : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

mapper/vgubuntu-root    : isnotESP, fstab-has-goodEFI,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p1   : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

mapper/vgubuntu-root    : not--sepboot, with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, sda
nvme0n1p1   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk nvme0n1: 476.94 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Disk identifier: 24F66302-F645-4715-82DE-55FBC01763DF
            Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
nvme0n1p1    2048    1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
nvme0n1p2 1050624 1000214527 999163904 476.4G Linux LVM
Disk mapper/vgubuntu-root: 474.53 GiB, 509519855616 bytes, 995155968 sectors
Disk mapper/vgubuntu-swap_1: 1.91 GiB, 2051014656 bytes, 4005888 sectors
Disk sda: 14.65 GiB, 15728640000 bytes, 30720000 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x00271743
      Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
sda1  *     2048 30719999 30717952 14.6G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:15.7GB:scsi:512:512:msdos:Generic Flash Disk:;
1:1049kB:15.7GB:15.7GB:fat32::boot, lba;
mapper/vgubuntu-root:510GB:dm:512:512:loop:Linux device-mapper (linear):;
1:0.00B:510GB:510GB:ext4::;
mapper/vgubuntu-swap_1:2051MB:dm:512:512:loop:Linux device-mapper (linear):;
1:0.00B:2051MB:2051MB:linux-swap(v1)::;
nvme0n1:512GB:nvme:512:512:gpt:PC601 NVMe SK hynix 512GB:;
1:1049kB:538MB:537MB:fat32:EFI System Partition:boot, esp;
2:538MB:512GB:512GB:::lvm;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME                FSTYPE      UUID                                   PARTUUID                             LABEL       PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                                     
â””â”€sda1              vfat        4665-3B2A                              00271743-01                          UBUNTU 22_0 
nvme0n1                                                                                                                 
â”œâ”€nvme0n1p1         vfat        21F1-FD7A                              5ad9202a-0041-401f-a660-ad899188dd67             EFI System Partition
â””â”€nvme0n1p2         LVM2_member cyFh5U-otD8-seps-ETlo-2IBo-N34Z-ufwVI2 85ef1d2d-2ab2-4b85-8597-9f31a94a6eb3             
  â”œâ”€vgubuntu-root   ext4        03842af3-572e-4c73-acd2-0131b7a7da57                                                    
  â””â”€vgubuntu-swap_1 swap        102b1268-f936-4b50-b67b-ffba46a0f9f6                                                    

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                           Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root 296.6G  31% /media/ubuntu/03842af3-572e-4c73-acd2-0131b7a7da57
/dev/sda1                  11.1G  24% /cdrom

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________


============================== ls -R /dev/mapper/ ==============================

/dev/mapper:
control
vgubuntu-root
vgubuntu-swap_1

=================== nvme0n1p1/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg (filtered) ===================

search.fs_uuid 03842af3-572e-4c73-acd2-0131b7a7da57 root lvmid/rAktHk-GUyS-Sstt-Zd36-E0gn-27Ku-wjW1y3/sTB0ZP-th2W-KcMQ-crCq-qqlT-crQK-alPepT 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

====================== sda1/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Try or Install Ubuntu
Ubuntu (safe graphics)
OEM install (for manufacturers)
Boot from next volume
UEFI Firmware Settings
Test memory

==================== sda1: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1


==================== blkid (filtered) before lvm activation ====================

/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root: UUID="03842af3-572e-4c73-acd2-0131b7a7da57" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/nvme0n1p1: UUID="21F1-FD7A" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="5ad9202a-0041-401f-a660-ad899188dd67"
/dev/sda1: LABEL="UBUNTU 22_0" UUID="4665-3B2A" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="00271743-01"
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-swap_1: UUID="102b1268-f936-4b50-b67b-ffba46a0f9f6" TYPE="swap"
/dev/nvme0n1p2: UUID="cyFh5U-otD8-seps-ETlo-2IBo-N34Z-ufwVI2" TYPE="LVM2_member" PARTUUID="85ef1d2d-2ab2-4b85-8597-9f31a94a6eb3"


================================ LVM activation ================================

modprobe dm-mod  
vgscan --mknodes
  Found volume group "vgubuntu" using metadata type lvm2
vgchange -ay
  2 logical volume(s) in volume group "vgubuntu" now active
lvscan
  ACTIVE            '/dev/vgubuntu/root' [<474.53 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/vgubuntu/swap_1' [1.91 GiB] inherit
blkid -g



Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility will purge (in order to enable-lvm) and reinstall the grub-efi of
mapper/vgubuntu-root,
using the following options:  nvme0n1p1/boot/efi
Additional repair will be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s use-standard-efi-file



Final advice in case of suggested repair: ______________________________________

Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the Ubuntu 22.10 entry (nvme0n1p1/efi/****/grub****.efi (**** will be updated in the final message) file) !
```

Is there any way to fix it or i need to install a fresh one?

Comment: If you deleted `/bin`, etc it is not about repairing boot. You need to re-install.

Comment: Yeah i have deleted bin, lib and sbin directories

Comment: You deleted everything ;-)